# Equivalence of certain set being a field and irreducibility of minimal polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Fix a field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $\mathbb{F}[x]$ denote the polynomial ring. Suppose $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and define $P := \{ q(A) : q \in \mathbb{F}[x] \}$.  Also denote by $p \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ the minimal polynomial of $A$.

It's not hard to check that $P$ is a  subring of $M_n(\mathbb{F})$, and both are vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ if we restrict to addition only. Since $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ is finite dimensional, it follows that $P$ is also finite-dimensional.

Now I'm trying to show that $P$ is a field ( when viewed as a ring) if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ is irreducible.  First, without any assumptions of the irreducibility of $p$ It's easy to verify all the field axioms up to inverses.
So now fix some non-zero $y \in P$ and  define a map $f_y :  P \rightarrow P, \, x \mapsto xy$. It's quick to check that $f$ is linear, when $P$ is viewed as a vector space.

Then the crux of the argument comes down to showing the kernel of $f_y$ is trivial if and only if $p$ is irreducible, from which the result would then follow because we would then have injectivity of a linear map on a finite-dimensional vector space, guaranteeing surjectivity also, which can be seen to provide an inverse for $y$. However, I am stuck on this part.

My attempt so far.
Reverse direction, suppose $p$ is irreducible. Suppose $x \in \text{ker}(f_y) \implies xy = 0$. Let $q,r \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $r(A) = x$ and $q(A) = y$.  Since $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, $p$ must divide $rq$. Then stuck on how to show this implies $x $ is the zero matrix.
For the forward direction, I am also stuck. Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose $p$ is irreducible in $F[x]$. Let $q\in F[x]$ be a polynomial such that $q(A)\ne 0$. In particular $q$ is not divisible by $p$, and since $p$ is irreducible it follows that $\gcd(q,p)=1$. Hence there are some $k,l\in F[x]$ such that:

$kq+lp=1$

If we substitute $A$ into both sides we get $k(A)q(A)=1$. So we have shown that if $q(A)\ne 0$ then it is an invertible element in $P$. Thus $P$ is a field.

Conversely, suppose that $p$ is reducible. Then there are polynomials $a,b\in F[x]$ which satisfy $ab=p$ and $\deg(a),\deg(b)<\deg(p)$. Since $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ it follows that $a(A), b(A)\ne 0$. However, $a(A)b(A)=p(A)=0$. So in this case $P$ is not even an integral domain, so for sure it is not a field.